# Open source AutoCAD alternative for Linux?

Tags: linux, autocad

Is there any good open source AutoCAD alternative that is used by (semi)-professionals or is AutoCAD the standard?

Comment: I am sure this has come up before, but I can't find it... Try looking here http://www.osalt.com/autocad - but, Autocad pretty much is the best, finding an alternative really depends on what you are going to be using it for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your requirements you might consider Google Sketchup, apparently some people have had some success running it using Wine. http://wiki.winehq.org/GoogleSketchup

It's been some years since I wrote software for AutoCAD but I was always under the impression that it was the market standard, with the possible exception of [Solid Works](http://www.solidworks.com/) which also has a market share.

If you are having to send drawings to other people or receive their drawings you will most likely find that they are going to be using DWG (AutoCAD) files and you will need a facility to view if not edit them.

The [Open Design Alliance](http://www.opendwg.org/) have tools for viewing and to an extent editing DWG files but I'm not sure about their level of Linux support.

Comment: Can Blender be used somewhat like SketchUp? I've seen it listed as an alternative to SketchUp somewhere, but I'm not sure whether I should recommend studying it to a person who is used to drawing plans for country-side buildings (as an amateur) in SketchUpand who wants to use GNU/Linux as the OS.

Comment: Regarding Blender: http://askubuntu.com/a/50072/19753 says Blender i much more complex to learn...

Answer (score 3):

You can find a few alternatives [here](http://alternativeto.net/desktop/autocad/?license=free&sort=likes)

Comment: Thank you for the link. I have never been on that site before and I think it is very useful